# How to safely clean up resource fork files?

Tags: filesystem, storage, automation, macos

I'm trying to clean up my hard drive to recover some disk space. Part of what I'm doing is merging two large directories of image files that I know have lots of duplicates because they were two copies originated from the same set of files. The two directories are quite large so I moved (`mv`) one to an external hard drive first. Then I used rsync to copy/merge the two folders

```
rsync -thrivpb '/Volumes/external_harddrive/image_temp/' '/Users/glds/image'
```

Then I noticed a lot of resource fork files with the file names `._XXX` were also being copied over. I suspect that many of those are not necessary. Is there a way to safely clean up unnecessary resource files in the destination folder now?

I've searched on Internet and couldn't find a good and recent enough reference that I feel comfortable to follow.

Two tentative approaches I'm considering:

- Find and delete all resource files using `find`:

  ```
  find . -type f -iname '._*' -exec rm '{}' \;
  ```

  But some references, potentially outdated and invalid though, do recommend against simply deleting resource files. So I'm not sure.
- Use the `dot_clean` command to merge the resource fork to its corresponding file. I found a 10-year old reference at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5192627 on this approach which essentially uses

  ```
  dot_clean -m
  ```

However, I'm unable to follow its exact instruction as the  "Service" mentioned in the step "Select Service as the type of workflow" is no longer available in macOS 13's Automator.

- Update 1:
  The external hard drive is ExtFAT. The main hard drive where `image/` is is APFS.

Comment: What kind of attributes are you talking about?  Stuff like Finder info, custom icons, tags, and labels probably wouldn't be an issue, but some older formats stored the actual image data in the resource fork.

Comment: @red_menace: I don't know how to check.

Comment: The answer with respect to `dot_clean` depends on the format of the volume where the files reside. For example, the `dot_clean` command with the same parameters could perform a different operation on a JHFS+ formatted volume versus a FAT32 formatted volume.

Comment: I suspect that the amount of space you will free up by deleting resource forks will be ooh, maybe as much as tens of Megabytes. And the risk of deleting something useful or crucial is large.

Comment: @benwiggy: I fail to see how the amount of space that you will free up by deleting resource forks has any relevancy to the OP's question. The use of `rsync` was used to recover some disk space. The desire to delete resource forks was not done in an effort to recover some additional  disk space.

Comment: @DavidAnderson The first sentence says the whole exercise was about recovering space. Then there's an assumption that the resource forks are unnecessary. It seemed worth saying that leaving the forks will avoid any unintended data loss, and will not unduly cost significant disk space.

Comment: @benwiggy: When a `_.*` file is copied from a ExFAT volume to an APFS volume by `rsync` as explained by the OP, the resource forks and other information stored in the `_.*` file is not longer associated with any other file. At this point (unless an appropriate dot_clean command is issued), the resource forks and other information for all practical purposes is LOST. This is a flaw in how `rsync` is designed. This flaw does not exist when `cp` or the Finder application is used to copy a file from ExFAT to APFS.

Comment: The OP copied a bunch of files directly to an external ExFAT volume, which caused the creation of `_.*` files. What the OP should have done is create an APFS sparse disk image file on the external ExFAT volume. The OP could then have attached this file and copied the bunch of files to the mounted APFS volume. Then no `_.*` files would have been created and problem would have gone away. After executing `rsync`, the OP could have detached and removed the sparse disk image file.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: That's neat. I didn't even know bout "APFS sparse disk image". I just read the Wikipedia article about "sparse file". Any concrete instruction on how to create that on macOS? Just use it as if it is a external hard drive?

Comment: qazwsx: I added how to create sparse disk image file to my answer. You can use it as if it is an external hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dot_clean` operations can depend on the file system. I will try to illustrate this through examples. Basicaly, the following will be shown.

- The `find . -type f -iname '._*' -exec rm '{}' \;` command does the same thing as the `dot_clean -m --keep=native .` command, which is to remove `._*` files.
- The `dot_clean -m .` command also removes `._*` files, but can also transfer information before removing the files.

### Initial Conditions

The `ls` command output below shows the contains of four volumes which are formatted as FAT32, APFS, ExFAT and JHFS+. The data fork of the `hi.txt` file in each volume is the same. The same is true for the `._bye.txt` and `._hi.txt` files in each volume. All previously existing `bye.txt` files have been removed.

```
davidanderson@Snapper /Volumes % ls -l@OeA /Volumes/MYFAT32 /Volumes/MyAPFS /Volumes/MyExFAT /Volumes/MyJHFS+   
/Volumes/MYFAT32:
total 32
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  hidden 4096 Nov 17 17:04 ._bye.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  hidden 4096 Nov 17 17:02 ._hi.txt
drwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  hidden 4096 Nov 17 18:49 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 davidanderson  staff  -        10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt
    com.apple.TextEncoding    15 
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS     16 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_df4faouox2jis4jyu5u6pu7qnu    89 

/Volumes/MyAPFS:
total 24
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  - 4096 Nov 17 17:04 ._bye.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  - 4096 Nov 17 17:02 ._hi.txt
drwxrwxrwx  7 davidanderson  staff  -  224 Nov 17 17:17 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  -   10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt

/Volumes/MyExFAT:
total 256
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  hidden  4096 Nov 17 17:04 ._bye.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  hidden  4096 Nov 17 17:02 ._hi.txt
drwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  hidden 32768 Nov 17 18:49 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 davidanderson  staff  -         10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt
    com.apple.TextEncoding     15 
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS      16 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_df4faouox2jis4jyu5u6pu7qnu     89 

/Volumes/MyJHFS+:
total 24
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  - 4096 Nov 17 17:04 ._bye.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  - 4096 Nov 17 17:02 ._hi.txt
drwxrwxrwx  7 davidanderson  staff  -  238 Nov 17 17:17 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  -   10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt
```

Note the following:

- The `hi.txt` file in the FAT32 and ExFAT volumes has extended attributes which are stored in the `._hi.txt` file.
- The `hi.txt` file in the APFS and JHFS+ volumes has no extended attributes. The extended attributes, which are stored in the `._hi.txt` file, are ignored.

### Case 1: Use of `find . -type f -iname '._*' -exec rm '{}' \;`

Below the `find . -type f -iname '._*' -exec rm '{}' \;` command was modified to act on the four volumes as given in the Initial Conditions section. The results are shown below.

```
davidanderson@Snapper /Volumes % find /Volumes/MYFAT32 /Volumes/MyAPFS /Volumes/MyExFAT /Volumes/MyJHFS+ -type f -iname '._*' -exec rm '{}' \;
davidanderson@Snapper /Volumes % ls -l@OeA /Volumes/MYFAT32 /Volumes/MyAPFS /Volumes/MyExFAT /Volumes/MyJHFS+
/Volumes/MYFAT32:
total 16
drwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  hidden 4096 Nov 17 18:49 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  -        10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt

/Volumes/MyAPFS:
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  7 davidanderson  staff  - 224 Nov 17 17:17 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  -  10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt

/Volumes/MyExFAT:
total 128
drwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  hidden 32768 Nov 17 18:49 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  -         10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt

/Volumes/MyJHFS+:
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  7 davidanderson  staff  - 238 Nov 17 17:17 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  -  10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt
```

Note the following:

- All `._*` files have been removed.
- None of the `hi.txt` files have extended attributes.

### Case 2: Use of `dot_clean -m .`

Below the `dot_clean -m .` command was modified to act on the four volumes as given in the Initial Conditions section. The results are shown below.

```
davidanderson@Snapper /Volumes % dot_clean -m /Volumes/MYFAT32 /Volum/MyAPFS /Volumes/MyExFAT /Volumes/MyJHFS+
davidanderson@Snapper /Volumes % ls -l@OeA /Volumes/MYFAT32 /Volumes/MyAPFS /Volumes/MyExFAT /Volumes/MyJHFS+
/Volumes/MYFAT32:
total 16
drwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  hidden 4096 Nov 17 19:32 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  -        10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt

/Volumes/MyAPFS:
total 16
drwxrwxrwx  7 davidanderson  staff  - 224 Nov 17 17:17 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 davidanderson  staff  -  10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt
    com.apple.ResourceFork  286 
    com.apple.TextEncoding   15 
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS    16 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_df4faouox2jis4jyu5u6pu7qnu   89 

/Volumes/MyExFAT:
total 128
drwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  hidden 32768 Nov 17 19:32 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  -         10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt

/Volumes/MyJHFS+:
total 16
drwxrwxrwx  7 davidanderson  staff  - 238 Nov 17 17:17 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 davidanderson  staff  -  10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt
    com.apple.ResourceFork  286 
    com.apple.TextEncoding   15 
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS    16 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_df4faouox2jis4jyu5u6pu7qnu   89
```

Note the following:

- All `._*` files have been removed.
- The `hi.txt` file in the FAT32 and ExFAT volumes has no extended attributes.
- The `hi.txt` file in the APFS and JHFS+ volumes has extended attributes. The extended attributes were copied from the `._hi.txt` file before the `._hi.txt` file was removed.

### Case 3: Use of `dot_clean -m --keep=native .`

Below the `dot_clean -m --keep=native .` command was modified to act on the four volumes as given in the Initial Conditions section. The results are shown below.

```
davidanderson@Snapper /Volumes % dot_clean -m --keep=native /Volumes/MYFAT32 /Volumes/MyAPFS /Volumes/MyExFAT /Volumes/MyJHFS+
davidanderson@Snapper /Volumes % ls -l@OeA /Volumes/MYFAT32 /Volumes/MyAPFS /Volumes/MyExFAT /Volumes/MyJHFS+                
/Volumes/MYFAT32:
total 16
drwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  hidden 4096 Nov 17 19:37 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  -        10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt

/Volumes/MyAPFS:
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  7 davidanderson  staff  - 224 Nov 17 17:17 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  -  10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt

/Volumes/MyExFAT:
total 128
drwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  hidden 32768 Nov 17 19:37 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  -         10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt

/Volumes/MyJHFS+:
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  7 davidanderson  staff  - 238 Nov 17 17:17 .fseventsd
-rwxrwxrwx  1 davidanderson  staff  -  10 Nov 17 17:02 hi.txt
```

Note the following:

- All `._*` files have been removed.
- None of the `hi.txt` files have extended attributes.
- The results are the same as Case 1.

---

macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 was used to test this answer.

---

### Creating and Attaching (Mounting) a Sparse Disk Image File.

The problems posted in the question could have been avoided by create an APFS formatted sparse image on the external ExFAT formatted drive.

1. Open the Disk Utility application.
2. From the menu bar, select `File` > `New Image` > `Blank Image...`
3. Fill out the popup. An example is given below.

   [image]